# Angular 12 update - The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have updated my project to the latest angular version.
After updating with "`ng update`" I receive the message that everything is up to date.
(The last step in my process. The required packages are already updated)

Nice, but when I serve the project I get the following error:

```
Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.2.3 and <4.3.0 but 4.3.2 was found instead.
```

I already tried: `npm install typescript@4.3.0` but that version does not exist. I prefer not to downgrade. I trying to keep my projects up to date.

How can I fix this.

Comment: Note it says `<4.3.0`, so 4.3.0 wouldn't be valid anyway. You need to install 4.2.4. *"I prefer not to downgrade"* - if your dependencies require a different version, that's not really your choice.

Comment: Make sure you refer [https://update.angular.io/](https://update.angular.io/) during updates. Its a great utility

Answer (score 3):

As the comments already states, Angular only supports typescript 4.2 for now. The newest supported version can be installed with

```
npm i typescript@4.2.*
```

If you **really** want to use the newest typescript, the flag *disableTypeScriptVersionCheck* can be set in your tsconfig (although not recommended):
https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck

Answer (score 1):

Angular 12 only supports Typescript 4.2.
You have to modify your `package.json` like this.

```
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
```

And re-run `npm install`.